# HTML5 auto scroll to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

As you can see right here: https://www.sequoiacap.com/

I'm trying to mimic its scrolling behavior right here, and its implementation really baffles me. Is it scrolling to another section? Or is it scrolling the background? Is there a name for this specific website style?

I have a one page parallax theme that I would like to auto scroll for user, so that each scroll gives the user a new fullscreen section. I would like to know how many plugins I would need to use. Some basic examples or directions for research would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sequoiacap is just using a full screen image slider plugin. Basically its a slider that is covering the entire page. In the slider they have custom designed images. What would you like to do?

Comment: @user1504265 I would like to 1. Know the technique's name, so I can find similar themes on themeforest. 2. Learn how to implement this technique so I can make my one page parallax theme auto scroll to next section when user scrolls.

Comment: You can look for full page image slider templates. There is one in bootstrap call full slider.

Comment: @user1504265 thanks, will take a look.

Comment: https://codepen.io/igstudio/pen/pbYOab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's 2 possible ways out of many, for how you could implement this:

- [jump.js](http://callmecavs.com/jump.js/) which is a dependency-free library (meaning it does not require jQuery or similar)
- [fullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) which is a full page slider plugin for jQuery. This might be more of what you want, because it does not introduce a scrollbar.